# .joins with three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, associations

I have three models that needs to be joined together (there are 4 models in play, but I need to join only three of them). The 4 models are user, keyword, question, association.

These are the relationships in the models

1. A user has many keywords through associations
2. A keyword has many users through associations
3. Keyword has many questions
4. Questions belong to a keyword

The models are -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :keywords, :through => :associations 

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many :associations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :associations

  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy

class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword
  belongs_to :user

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword
```

Now I need to retrieve all questions for keywords for a particular user (e.g. user_id = 2) using .joins.

Any idea how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Question.joins(keyword: [:user]).where(users: {id: 2})
```

Comment: This gives me an error - "Association named 'user' was not found on Keyword; perhaps you misspelled it?"

Comment: Actually this worked fine, except I need details from both questions and keywords table. Details about questions are retrieved fine, but keyword details don't show up. I also tried to add .includes(:keyword) to no avail. Any suggestions on that? Also what purpose do the square brackets around user serve?

Comment: I used your code since I wanted details about question. Also I added select to it to select fields from keywords table.`Question.joins(keyword: [:users]).select("keywords.keyword, questions.*").where("users.id = @user.id)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
Keyword.joins(:questions, :users).includes(:questions).where(users: {id: 2})
```

Comment: When I run Keyword.joins(:questions, :users).includes(:questions).where(users: {id: 2}).to_sql on rails I get the following output. As you can see the select part of the SQL does not include questions. Any reasons why?? SELECT \"keywords\".* FROM \"keywords\" INNER JOIN \"questions\" ON \"questions\".\"keyword_id\" = \"keywords\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"associations\" ON \"associations\".\"keyword_id\" = \"keywords\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"users\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"associations\".\"user_id\" WHERE \"users\".\"id\" = 2

Comment: This seemed to work `Keyword.joins(:questions, :users).select("questions.*").where(users: {id: 2})`

Comment: :) . You cannot see `includes` query by using `to_sql` .

Comment: If I use includes in the above query as you have recommended in your answer, I don't see attributes for questions in the output. To see the attributes of questions in the output, I have to use select instead of includes as mentioned by my comment above. Not sure why. what's the purpose of includes then?

Comment: includes is for eager loading(http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/) to solve n+1 query problem. If you don't have that issue avoid that.